# Understanding Google's tutorial on BNN: Why the use of VariableLayers?

Tags: neural-networks, bayesian

In this [Google's tuto](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Probabilistic_Layers_Regression), when they define the prior and posterior, they use a [VariableLayer](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/layers/VariableLayer). From what I understood, this layer simply returns a trainable constant (the bias terms?) as output...

I think part of the objective pf the VariableLayer is to make the prior and posterior trainable.

1. How exactly does the VariableLayer helps us making them trainable? From the sequential way of building, it seems we're just passing some constants to the LambdaLayers...
2. Couldn't we just have used a usual Dense layer (by imposing a null kernel), instead of the VariableLayer?
3. What's the point in making the prior trainable?